# magento2 drop down custom options price want to change

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, custom-options

In magento 2 there are two price types fixed and percentage that's fine.

Now I have a simple product with drop down custom options and i have created a new custom price type like (SQM) in the backend.

Please find the below scree shots.

[image]

[image]

I would like to show my custom option prices in the respected drop down options based on the price type(sqm),

As well once i select the option the respected price want to add to product price accordingly.

could you please suggest me or help me how i can achieve this?

**Note:** Sqm=x+y+z;